# Generate permutations of size n from given list, where each permutations must contain all of the original values, possibly repeated

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I was trying to create a small script that will take the list of elements and create all the possible permutations of its contents, while all those permutations may have repetitions and have to be of size n and contain all the original values. I tried to use the `itertools` library but they don't have anything of use. Is there something simple I can do to achieve that?

Here is an example for the list `[0,1,2]` and `n=3`:

```
[0,1,2]
[0,2,1]
[1,0,2]
[2,0,1]
[1,2,0]
[2,1,0]
```

For `n=4`, something like `[0,1,1,2]` will also be allowed in the output.

Comment: what's wrong with `permutations()`? It does tolerate repeated elements (as it works internally with indices, not values).

Comment: @PierreD `permutations` tolerates repeated elements in the input sequence, but it doesn't generate repeated elements in the output sequence. Using `permuations([0,1,2], 4)` yields an empty sequence, not a sequence containing `(0,1,1,2)`.

Comment: in that case, the question should be edited for clarity and focus on a case that is not directly served by the standard `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described can be implemented with the following function:

```
def perms_with_duplicates(lst: list, n: int) -> Iterator:
    """
    Generate permutations of ``lst`` with length ``n``. 
    If ``n`` is greater than the length of ``lst``, then the
    resulting permutations will include duplicate elements 
    from ``lst``. All of the original elements of ``lst``
    are guaranteed to appear in each output permutation.
    """
    
    # Number of duplicate entries that the permutations can include.
    num_dupl = max(n - len(lst) + 1, 1)
    
    return itertools.permutations(lst * num_dupl, n)
```

Alternatively, if you need this to work over any [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), instead of just for lists, you could use

```
def perms_with_duplicates(seq: Sequence, n: int) -> Iterator:
    """
    Generate permutations of ``seq`` with length ``n``. 
    If ``n`` is greater than the length of `seq`, then the
    resulting permutations will include duplicate elements 
    from ``seq``. All of the original elements of ``seq``
    are guaranteed to appear in each output permutation.
    """
    
    # Number of duplicate entries that the permutations can include.
    num_dupl = max(n - len(seq) + 1, 1)

    it_dupl =  itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.repeat(seq, num_dupl)
    )
    
    return itertools.permutations(it_dupl, n)
```

Both functions behave as follows. Note that for `n` less than or equal to the length of the input sequence, the functions behave exactly like `itertools.permutations`.

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2]

>>> list(perms_with_duplicates(l, 3))                                                                                                
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]

>>> len(list(perms_with_duplicates(l, 4)))
360

>>> list(perms_with_duplicates(l, 4))                                                                                                
[(0, 1, 2, 0),
 (0, 1, 2, 1),
 (0, 1, 2, 2),
 (0, 1, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 ...
 (1, 2, 1, 0),
 (1, 2, 1, 0),
 (1, 2, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0, 0),
 (1, 2, 0, 1),
 ...
 (2, 1, 0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). [[New in 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#new-improved-and-deprecated-modules)]

If the sequence length n is equal to number of unique elements, as in your example, then trivially there can be no repetitions, so this would reduce to [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Else for the general case, use a list comprehension to filter the raw output from [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

elems = [0,1,1,2]

[comb for comb in combinations_with_replacement(elems, 4) if all(el in comb for el in elems)]

[(0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: @Brian: oh is that what "contain all the unique values" means, (as opposed to "the entire output should contain all the unique values").

Comment: @Brian implemented it

Comment: This answer misses many of the permutations that the OP expects (for example, when `n=3`, it yields `[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]` instead of the 6 unique sequences the OP asked for). It's also unnecessarily wasteful, since you're generating _combinations_ and then filtering out the combinations that aren't valid _permutations_. I'm not sure if `combinations_with_replacement` is really of any help for this problem.